# Python 3.3, Beautiful Soup 4, 503 and Reiteration

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup

With my project I see two problems:

1. 8/10 times I receive `HTTP Error 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable`.
2. Am I performing reiteration correctly?

I need to look for a class called `class="torType"` and then just get the link URLs, I have it working kind of, but am I doing it correctly?

```
#import urllib.request
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
WebUrl = 'http://kickasstorrents.come.in/tv/'

def RetrieveWebData(MyUrl):
     try:
         opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
         opener.addheaders =[('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0')]
         url = (MyUrl)
         page = opener.open(url).read()
         return page
    except OSError as e:
        print("An error occurred reading the webpage ",e)


def FilterWebData(RawData):
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(RawData)
        TorData = soup.find_all("a", {"class" : "torType"})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(str(TorData))
        for link in soup.find_all('a'):
            RecentTors = link.get('href')
        return RecentTors

    except OSError as e:
        print("An error occurred during filtering",e)


RawPage = RetrieveWebData(WebUrl)
RecentTorrentLinks = FilterWebData(RawPage)


print(RecentTorrentLinks)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intermittent HTTP 503 error you're getting is related to high load on the given URL.

You may want to add that inside `except` block of `RetrieveWebData()`:

```
    if e.code == 503:
        return RetrieveWebData(MyUrl)
```

When it fail for some reason, the function will call itself again recursively until it didn't get the HTTP 503 error.

Furthermore, this `FilterWebData()` line is wrong:

```
        RecentTors = link.get('href')
```

You're overwriting `RecentTors` variable each iteration. You really want to do something like that:

```
    RecentTors = []
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        RecentTors += [link.get('href')]
    return RecentTors
```

I'd suggest you to use the fastest [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) module to take advantage of XPath:

```
def FilterWebData(RawData):
    try:
        TorData = []

        for RecentTor in etree.HTML(RawData).xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'torType')]"):
            TorData += [RecentTor.attrib['href']]

        return TorData
    except OSError as e:
        print("An error occurred during filtering",e)
```

That's all!

Comment: Thanks for that, is lmxl part of beautifulsoup, sorry just a beginner. would speed be an issue on the specific page I am looking at, it only retrieves the around about 10 items. ? Thanks :)

Comment: @DeadZero Nope, `lxml` is another module which works with HTML/XML parsing and supports XPath. You can get more info here: http://lxml.de/ I think in this page speed won't be an issue for you, but overall `lxml` tends to be more faster and have the advantage of supporting XPath, which in some cases would be much easier to achieve whatever you want. :)

Answer (score 2):

The 503 errors you see are probably due to the server rate limiting you, hit the server less frequently.

The loop is incorrect; loop over the `TorData` objects directly. You can limit the search to only those `a` links that have a `href` attribute too:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(RawData)
TorData = soup.find_all("a", {"class" : "torType", 'href': True})
return [link['href'] for link in TorData]
```

Comment: Cool, Thanks I will go give the Loop a try and see how it hangs together,  hmm not hitting the server to much , I have only run that script manually every now and then at the moment while I am trying to create it and test it. strange tho, I run it, 503 fails, I run it again immediately straight after it works.

Comment: Then the server is just generally overloaded.

Comment: Hey Martijn , both yours and Paulo are correct in helping me, I am going to award the correct answer to Paulo Freitas though if your don't mind, your answered is correct (have it stored so I can make sense of the additional entries) and thanks for the help, but Paulo added adding code of capturing the e.code and the solution is similar to mycode( not as elegant as yours) but I understand it what its doing better(beginner :/) , not sure what the lmxl is about tho. haha, mark both of them correct would be nice :)

Comment: And congratulations on reaching 15 points, you can now vote on posts too!